# Lucene/Solr - how to return both relevant documents and authors based on query presence in documents?

Tags: solr, search-engine

We have successfully implemented Apache Solr to return the x most relevant dialogs as search results in our dialoging system.

Every dialog (node.nid) consists of comments (comment.cid), and each dialog/comment is authored by a user (node.uid / comment.uid).

Currently, Solr is configured to search through all dialog content (comments, users, timestamps etc). We would like to expand our search results to not only display dialogs most relevant to a query, but also return the most relevant authors.

The problem is that in order to determine the relevance of authors with respect to a query, we need Solr to distinguish between nodes and comments, and node.uid's and comment.uid's respectively.

Is it at all possible to return different types of search results using Solr: dialogs and authors, e.g. first displaying the top 5 authors with respect to a search query and then the top 50 relevant queries with respect to that same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to return different types of search results using Solr.
Solr has an open schema, meaning that you can index whatever you want in Solr,
as long as each document has a unique id. Thus, you can index authors and dialogs in the same Solr index. They should probably have different fields (e.g. author name and their dialog texts for author, just the dialog text for a dialog).

I believe the [DisMax query mode](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMax) might help you, in scoring authors and dialogs differently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm currently giving it a try and experimenting with querying against the renewed index and displaying results.

Comment: BTW - is there any real objection against running 2 Solr instances for different object types (in this case documents and authors/users)? Except for more or less double use of capacity of course. The reason I'm asking is that the dialog search is pretty much mature, but the author/user search leaves much to be tweaked/tuned, and adjusting the index and such will require re-indexing, thus interfering with the dialog search.

Comment: Well, I suggest that you use different cores within the same Solr instance: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin. I have used Solr cores  for different languages in multilingual search. They let you have separate indexes without paying the price of double resource consumption.

Comment: Multiple cores was the answer. I'm now running two solr cores, one solr instance, with both core indexes populated by different schema's. The next step is to correctly return search results from both cores based on 1 query (probably duplicated and then fed to both cores).